# State space reduction of a CTMC

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a CTMC with six states $\{0,1,\ldots,5\}$. It turns out that states 3 and 4 are equivalent and so are states 1, 2 and 5. I would love to clump equivalent states into one.

$$Q_1=\matrix {& 0 & 1 & 2 &  3 & 4 & 5 \cr
0 & -\lambda &  \lambda  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
1 & 0  & -(\mu+\lambda) & \lambda & 0 & \mu & 0\cr
2 & 0 & 0 & -2\mu & \mu & 0 & \mu \cr
3 & 0  &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 
4 & 0  &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 
5 & 0  &  0  & 0 & \mu & 0 & -\mu \cr 
}$$

In that case, is it alright to use the alternative reduced CTMC, with rate matrix $Q_2$ as follows?

$$Q_2=\matrix {& 0 & 1, 2, 5 &  3,4 \cr
0& -\lambda &  \lambda  & 0 \cr
1, 2, 5 & 0 & -\mu & \mu \cr
3,4 & 0 & 0 & 0
}$$

The intuition is that in each of the three states $\{1,2,5\}$ the out-rate to states $\{3,4\}$ is the same and is equal to $\mu$. However, I am not sure about one thing: in a CTMC, the time one stays in a state $i$ is given by $\exp(q_{ii})$. I could not find a way to find the new rate of staying in the same state.

In general, when is it legal to collapse the state space of a CTMC? Are there conditions imposed on the values in the rate matrix?

Comment: "It turns out that states 3 and 4 are equivalent and so are states 1, 2 and 5." Certainly not, at least in the usual sense. For example, the probability to visit 4 is 0 when starting from 3 and 1 when starting from 4. And so on. You might want to explain in which sense these states would be "equivalent".

Comment: Hi @did, I meant the equivalence was exogenous, i.e., not pertaining to the existing rates or the CTMC. The states are similar in my model, so I simply want to clump these states together and form a new CTMC (if that could be done).

Comment: I see. Please refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/27538/6179 or http://math.stackexchange.com/a/115976/6179. The relevant key-word is "lumpability".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27538/6179) or to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115976/6179). The relevant key-word is *lumpability*.